# Why Unity assembly definition raises an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**=== EDIT ===**

I get this error message: `The type 'TextMeshProUGUI' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Unity.TextMeshPro, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

**I know** what it means and how to fix it, my question is why it happens???

If you look at my code, it doesn't suppose to happen because I don't reference the TextMeshPro directly, but a class that wraps it.

When I call a function from the `Label` class, the code compiles fine, but when I call a function from the base class (`GraphicControl`) it doen't compile anymore.

I guess that it is because the `GraphicControl` class is referenced as `GraphicControl<TextMeshProUGUI>` which requires a reference to `TextMeshPro` and therefore the error.

But can some one confirm that? Or knows other reason it happenes.
(In Rider, I don't get any exception by the way).

In my project I have a UI assembly that manages everything related to UI.

I want that other assemblies that depends on UI, would reference this assembly only (Without TextMeshPro assembly, because it already referenced in the UI assembly).

This is my code:

```
public abstract class GraphicControl<TGraphic> where TGraphic : Graphic
{
    protected readonly TGraphic graphic;
    protected GraphicControl(TGraphic graphic) =>this.graphic = graphic;

    public bool RaycastTarget
    {
        get => graphic.raycastTarget;
        set => graphic.raycastTarget = value;
    }
}

public class Label : GraphicControl<TextMeshProUGUI>
{
    public Label(TextMeshProUGUI graphic) : base(graphic){}

    public void SetText(string text) => graphic.text = text;
}
```

The error occurs when I try to access the `RaycastTarget` property, like this:

```
Label l = UIManager.GetLabel(); //Creates the label in the UI assembly.
l.RaycastTarget = true; // Gives the Missing reference error in Unity.

l.SetText("Hello"); // Doesn't give an error, although it obviously uses the TextMeshProUGUI class.
```

Why does it happens¿

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: @slipz I am not next to the computer, but something like `Missing reference, can't use TextMeshProUGUI, you need to add reference to TextMeshPro assembly`.
Something along those lines.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Thats what I ask, why¿
I have built it that way, so I don't need to reference TextMeshPro.
Why using function in the label class is OK, but from the base class isn't

Comment: Removing the [tag:assembly] tag as it is meant for questions about assembly language.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry about that, I forgot that it it a programming language.

Comment: Hi do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, no one said that my assumption is wrong, so I guess I was right after all.

I still don't completely understand why Rider doesn't show an error but it doesn't matter.

The fix was to create an empty class that inherits from `TextMeshProUGUI`, that way I don't need to reference the TextMeshPro assembly.

This is my solution:

```
public abstract class GraphicControl<TGraphic> where TGraphic : Graphic
{
    protected readonly TGraphic graphic;
    protected GraphicControl(TGraphic graphic) =>this.graphic = graphic;

    public bool RaycastTarget
    {
        get => graphic.raycastTarget;
        set => graphic.raycastTarget = value;
    }
}

public class TextComponent : TextMeshProUGUI {}

public class Label : GraphicControl<TextComponent>
{
    public Label(TextMeshProUGUI graphic) : base(graphic){}

    public void SetText(string text) => graphic.text = text;
}
```